# Dynamics SL Field Length limit / Invoice Number length

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-sl

If anyone can point me to the documentation for SL, which address the field length limits, right now i need to know about the length limit of invoice number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where the documentation is, but the way I figure out the field length limits is with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) (SSMS). You can look at the databases and various tables/fields and figure out how big each field is as well as myriad of other information.

To find out the invoice number field length with SSMS I would connect to the Dynamics SL Company database (not the system database). The invoice number is a part of the accounts payable (AP) screens, so I would expand the `APDOC` table. Once you've done that you will see a few folders, one of which is the `Columns` folder. Expand the `Columns` folder and you will be presented with a list of fields. Within the parenthesis next to each of those fields you will find the length. In your case you will want to look at the `InvcNbr` field which is 15 characters for me, which I believe is the out of the box length.

An alternative method is to use customize mode within Dynamics SL. If you open up any screen that has the invoice number field, like `Voucher and Adjustment Entry` you can open up customize mode using the menu at the top of the screen. Next, open up the `Property Window` either by using the customize menu or hitting `F4`. Next, select the field you want to know the length for. For all character fields there will be a property called `Mask` that will be filled with several Xs. To figure out the field length, you simply need to count the number of Xs.

These 2 methods should be fairly future proof and will allow you to not have to search for the documentation for whatever version of Dynamics SL you might be on.